# Why can IIS make an API call on one server, but not another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, and one of the actions makes a post request on a web API, like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ...
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    string result = client.UploadString("https://path/to/api/endpoint", "POST", json);
  }
  ...
}
```

Locally, in Visual Studio, it works fine and is getting back the right data. The application is supposed to be published to two servers. One of them is the same server that has the API. When I publish to the server without the API, it works fine, but on the server with the API, it crashes, saying, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I don't know if this would be caused by an IIS setting that would prevent WebClient from working properly, or if it has something to do with the fact that it is on the same domain as the API. Any ideas?

Comment: Does port 443 traffic work at all from (not to) the IIS server? Is the SSL cert's signing authority in the server's trusted root certificate authorities list?

Comment: That exception message indicates a typical networking issue, so you should check that area, such as DNS/proxy and so on.